# Stop Function form runnning Javascript (function that repeats itself)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question has been asked before, but none of those solutions have worked for me. 
My situation is this, I have some javascript that changes the color of a div randomly and repeats itself to continuously.
 This causes a lot of lag on mobile, so when on mobile, I want the function not to run and to be replaced with a CSS animation.

Today I'm interested in the stopping the function from running part. Below is my code, but it doesn't work. Any help?

```
<script id="PC-Code">
// complicated function, ending with this:
all2 = colorizeAll2( tris2, 750, 2000 );
all2();
</script>

<script>
    if (
  /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(
    navigator.userAgent
  )
) {
  $("#PC-Code").remove();
}
</script>
```

Why does this not stop the javascript? How can I stop the javascript?

Comment: I don't know what your `colorizeAll2()` looks like, but you would need to set a variable and do stop it based on the variable's value. you can't simply remove javascript from a page like that, it's already loaded into memory, why not just always use css animations?

Comment: This only removes the script node, which was already parsed and is thus still being executed. You need to only activate that function at all if your RegExp test fails (PS: User Agent sniffing is considered bad practice and is not guaranteed to work in the future)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do your logic in the `PC-Code` script, and call `throw new Error` to stop it from executing if the condition meets, like:

```
if (
  /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(
    navigator.userAgent
){
    throw new Error('This script had to stop!')
}
```

Can you tell me if that did the trick?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "do your logic in PC-Code"? Do you mean the $("#PC-Code").remove(); in PC-Code?

Comment: I mean put this as the first line of ```<script id="PC-Code">
// complicated function, ending with this:
all2 = colorizeAll2( tris2, 750, 2000 );
all2();
</script>```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, at first it was doing some weird things but after a few refreshes it worked. Guess it had something to do with cache.

Comment: Glad I could help you out :) FYI, I just googled "stop script from running javascript", and looked at the first answer. You can do it yourself next time!

Answer (score 1):

What if you restructure your code so that the call to `all2()` only occurs if not mobile?

```
// remove all2(); from PC-code script

if (!(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(
    navigator.userAgent))
){
    all2();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe u can redefine u'r var to null if userAgent is mobile ?

```
<script id="PC-Code">
// complicated function, ending with this:
all2 = colorizeAll2( tris2, 750, 2000 );
all2();
</script>

<script>
    if (
  /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(
    navigator.userAgent
  )
) {
  all2 = null;
}
</script>
```

Comment: This won't stop the function from running, all it's doing is setting the reference that `all2` points at to `null`